# Is there any way to import the Google Play Console Install Report by REST API?

Tags: rest, google-play-console, qliksense

I am looking for ways to import the report by REST API (with signed URL) to Qlik Sense but no clues.

On the other hand, I have tried to use Data Transfer to BigQuery. It costs a lot as each install report of an app costs. (Trying to find a way that will be free or charging only one app)

I have also tried to transfer the data from Google Cloud Storage. However, it did not succeed as the files are not changed from utf-16 to utf-8.

I have searched for documentations and tried different solutions. Still, no clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use Qlik's own REST connector to achieve what you want.

The functionality is described here [Create a REST connection](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/REST_connector_help/Content/Connectors_REST/Create-REST-connection/Create-REST-connection.htm)

You mentioned trying to transfer from BigQuery, again there is a Qlik BigQuery connector
see this [Create a Google BigQuery Connection](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/ODBC_connector_help/Content/Connectors_ODBC/GoogleBigQuery/Create-GBQ-Connection.htm)

You also have the choice of using Qlik's Data Transfer tool explained here [Qlik Data Transfer](https://www.qlik.com/us/-/media/files/resource-library/global-us/direct/datasheets/ds-qlik-data-transfer-en.pdf).

Lastly importing from Google Cloud storage is also possible using the [Qlik Google Cloud Storage Web Storage Provider Connector](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/Web_Storage_Provider_Connectors_help/Content/Connectors_StorageProvider/Storage%20provider%20connectors/Google-Cloud-storage-provider-connector.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For Big Query, it imported successfully. However, it costs and we are finding way that will be free. For GCS connector, it does not include in my subscription of Qlik sense.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no free solution you will have to upgrade your Qlik subscription ..... or try using a project on GCP still within the free trial period

Comment: I see. Anyway, thank you for your help. Will discuss to my colleagues on this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need create POST request and store token into variable. In next step you will be able to create get request and download data.